# Django template system, how to get this property?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to know how to get this code working on Django.

This example WORKS:

View:

```
def index(request):    
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
    else:
        username = None
```

Template:

```
{{ username }}
```

Now what I want to do is this, but this is NOT WORKING:

View:

```
def index(request):    
    username = request.user.username
```

Template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ username }}
{% endif %}
```

Use the template in this way is possible? I am a beginner, I am just testing how things work here.

Any clue?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you pass `RequestContext` to your templates (which is true most of the time), you already have `request.user` aliased simply as `{{ user }}`. Then you do just

`{{ user.username }}`

and the view function needs to know nothing about this.

Answer (score 3):

Your second example probably isn't working because you haven't put `user` into the template context.  There isn't enough code to know for sure, and you haven't said what bad outcome you are seeing.